# Tell Grunt to put source into same target dir

Tags: gruntjs

Code that I have:

```
coffee: {
  compile: {
    files: {
      'server/api/**/*.js': ['server/api/**/*.coffee'] // compile and concat into single file
    }
  }
},
```

Meaning, the target Dir should be the same where the `.coffee` file was found. Above code in Grunt does however create the directory "**" and puts the file "*.js" into it.

This is what I want:

```
server/api/sample/sample.coffee   -> server/api/sample/sample.js
server/api/sample2/sample2.coffee -> server/api/sample2/sample2.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile your files dinamically you have to do it:

```
glob_to_multiple: {
  expand: true,
  flatten: true,
  cwd: 'server/api',
  src: ['**/*.coffee'],
  dest: 'server/api',
  ext: '.js',
  extDot: 'last'
}
```

Comment: Grunt creates the folder and file for you, you only need to pass the base path, in your case `server/api`. If you have a .coffee file in `server/api/foo/foo.coffee`, the destination will be `server/api/foo/foo.js`.

Comment: So far so good, with "flatten: false" stuff happens as described by your last comment. Except... for files like this "myFile.controller.coffee", they get renamed to "myFile.js". Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `extDot: 'last'`. In the documentation is better explained: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically